# Running Scilab from pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect, scilab

I am trying to run scilab using the pexpect module with the following code:

```
                import pexpect
                c=pexpect.spawn('scilab-adv-cli -nb')
                c.expect('-->')
```

When I do

```
                c.sendline('plot[1,2]')
```

the plot shows up. But when I do

```
                c.sendline('[1 2]*[3]')
                c.expect('ans  =')
```

followed by

```
                c.before
```

it gives me the following out put:

```
          '  =\r\n \r\n    3.    6.  \r\n \r\n\x1b[?1h\x1b=-->[1 2]*[3]\r\n\x1b[?1l\x1b> '
```

How can the above output be sanitised to obtain only say 3. 6. in the above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or give a try to:
http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/sciscipy/

Answer (score 1):

If all the output you want to read is that simple, then you can do:

```
largenum = 1000
# flush any remaining output
c.read_nonblocking(largenum)
c.sendline('[1 2]*[3]')
# discard unwanted lines until relevant line
for i in range(3): next(c)
# get answer (in this case, a single line)
ans = next(c).strip()
# discard rest of answer
c.read_nonblocking(largenum)
```

You probably know it, you are highly dependent on the way the scilab CLI outputs data.